# taking lon and lan using google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I should provide user with option to take lon and lan using gmap or some other map with pointing arrow to some place and store that value inside variable to process further.

Any thoughts, Thanks

Comment: I think you mean lat, not lan, but in any case what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this tutorial, it suits to your needs.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/a-google-maps-version-3-jquery-plugin/